# Typescript const (enum) works in VSCode but is not defined when building with NextJS

Tags: typescript, next.js, enums

I have a monorepo with a package that contains all of my Typescript types. I then pull these types into my other apps/packages and everything works fine. I now need an enum type. I started with Typescript enums but couldn't get them to work with isolatedModules set to true as required by Nextjs.

I now define my enums like this:

```
const NodeEnvironment = {
  Production: 'production',
  Development: 'development',
  Test: 'test',
} as const;

type NodeEnvironment = (typeof NodeEnvironment)[keyof typeof NodeEnvironment];
```

This works similar to Typescript enums and does everything that I want. In VSCode I can see the corresponding strings and autocomplete works well. I can use these types like this with no errors:

```
export const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === NodeEnvironment.Development;
```

However, when I build my app, `NodeEnvironment` is not defined. When I look at the compiled javascript, I see this:

```
\nconst isDev = \"development\" === NodeEnvironment.Development;
```

I would have expected that `NodeEnvironment.Development` would have been replaced with `development`. I'm not currently importing the type `NodeEnvironment` anywhere because I don't do that with any of the other types that I have (and I don't want to have to do that).

How do I get this to work?  What is the right way to define an enum type that works with NextJS?

Comment: You wouldn't import the `NodeEnvironment` type. You would import the variable `NodeEnvironment`. They're different things.

Comment: So is there any way to get this to work where I don't need to manually import these everywhere? I wanted to use const enums that are just replaced by strings on compile but I wasn't able to get that to with Nextjs.